# getting a min and max between two lists

Tags: python, list, compare, max, min

I'm trying to get the max and min between to lists in order to make a calculation later on but I keep getting a syntax error and I don't know what is wrong. here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats
data = pd.DataFrame({"concentratie": [0.05, 0.10, 0.15, 0.20, 0.30, 0.50, 0.75, 1.00], "absorptie": [0.415, 0.509, 0.573, 0.640, 0.686, 0.711, 0.724, 0.733], "Duplo": [0.446, 0.529, 0.622, 0.638, 0.675, 0.702, 0.715, 0.732]})

def function(absorptie, Duplo):
    list 3 = [max(value) for value in zip(data['absorptie'],data['Duplo'])]
    return list 3

def function(absorptie, Duplo):
    list 4 = [min(value) for value in zip(absorptie, Duplo)]
    return list 4
```

Comment: Please paste the complete traceback, as it will be helpful to us to know more

Comment: `list 3` is not a valid name for a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable name are not valid:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats
data = pd.DataFrame({"concentratie": [0.05, 0.10, 0.15, 0.20, 0.30, 0.50, 0.75, 1.00], "absorptie": [0.415, 0.509, 0.573, 0.640, 0.686, 0.711, 0.724, 0.733], "Duplo": [0.446, 0.529, 0.622, 0.638, 0.675, 0.702, 0.715, 0.732]})

def function(absorptie, Duplo):
    list_3 = [max(value) for value in zip(data['absorptie'],data['Duplo'])]
    return list_3

def function(absorptie, Duplo):
    list_4 = [min(value) for value in zip(absorptie, Duplo)]
    return list_4
```

Comment: You shouldn't just copy the solution in the comments

Comment: There was no comment when i begin to write my answer.

Comment: The comment was there already, maybe it was because you didn't see it